# Jenkins pipeline - file not found

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a simple pipeline job to:
1) checkout a git branch
2) cd to a run directory
3) execute an existing script to run tests

The pipeline script itself is very simple at this point:

```groovy
stage 'build'
node {
    git url: 'git@hd1:nip_5g_fpga', branch: "Phase_UL_1a"
    sh "pwd"
    sh "echo $PATH"
    sh "ls"
    dir ('nip_fpga/verification/src/UE/env/top_level/run') {
        sh "source vcs_bash.sh 1" 
    }
}
```

When I run this, I get the following error (showing only a part of the console):

```
Running
in /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/nip_regression_nightly/nip_fpga/verification/src/UE/env/top_level/run
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
[run] Running shell script
+ source vcs_bash.sh 1
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/nip_regression_nightly/nip_fpga/verification/src/UE/env/top_level/run@tmp/durable-c40e151e/script.sh: line 2: source: vcs_bash.sh: file not found
```

I have checked that vcs_bash.sh itself exists but it exists in `.../top_level/run` directory and not in `top_level/run@tmp` directory. So, I am confused how to get around this.

Also, I don't understand the concept of tmp directory that pipeline is creating

Comment: Jenkins will create a temporary file that and basically copy your contents and then execute the file, hence the `@tmp` dir/file.
It can happen that jenkins will tell you `file not found` when the default shell in jenkins is bash, but that is not installed on the node (i.e. it is a windows node or docker container without bash)

Comment: @Rik - I doubt if this is the case in the issue above. I will execute a bash command and check tomorrow. I am curious as to why Jenkins creates tmp directory for execution. I just want Jenkins to execute in my workspace.

Comment: Oh now I see. If you source the file. Can't you just execute it?

Comment: @Rik ... I just checked the workspace by logging in directly. Workspace has the files but attmp does not ... please see result of series of commands - **[rootathd1 top_level]# cd runattmp
[rootathd1 runattmp]# ls
[rootathd1 runattmp]# cd ..
[root@hd1 top_level]# ls
rtl  run  ruattmp  tb
[rootathd1 top_level]#**

Comment: @Sharanbr Have you solved this?

Comment: I am having the same issue, any resolution?

Comment: Any canonical resolution for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Knowing that pipeline jenkins plugin store the code from git on the folder *workspace@script*, I've used this little trick to access my sh file:

```
sh "../workspace@script/myScriptName.sh"
```